# Dynamic query SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, row

My table Input:

```
cd  SEQ status
DGH 1 Outstanding Requirement
OTH 1 Outstanding Requirement
OTH 2 O
OTH 3 O
OTH 1 Outstanding Requirement
OTH 2 O
OTH 3 O
OTH 4 O
OTH 5 O
```

I need output as below

```
cd  SEQ MyOrder
DGH 1   DGH-1
OTH 1   OTH-1
OTH 2   OTH-1
OTH 3   OTH-1
OTH 1   OTH-2
OTH 2   OTH-2
OTH 3   OTH-2
OTH 4   OTH-2
OTH 5   OTH-2
```

Comment: You need another column to establish an `order by` -- without it, you cannot guarantee the order of the results.

Answer (score 2):

As sgeddes mentioned, you need another column to establish the ordering you want. I'm going to assume you have an id column like this:

```
id cd  SEQ
1 DGH 1
2 OTH 1
3 OTH 2
4 OTH 3
5 OTH 1
6 OTH 2
7 OTH 3
8 OTH 4
9 OTH 5
```

Given this, you can use window functions to achieve what you want. Note that I'm assuming your table is called "items" below.

```
SELECT cd,
   SEQ,
   DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY items_grpd.cd ORDER BY items_grpd.grp) AS MyOrder
FROM
(
  SELECT id,
         cd,
         SEQ,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY cd ORDER BY id) - SEQ AS grp
  FROM items
) AS items_grpd
ORDER BY items_grpd.id;
```